# Sharing helm-buffers-list between multiple windows

Tags: helm

I use two separate windows in emacs, and when I use `helm-buffers-list`, it displays a list of files sorted with the most recently visited files near the top, however, this list is sorted differently for each window.  I'd like this list to be sorted the same way between all windows, rather than have a per-window sorted buffer list. Can anyone tell me how I can modify this behaviour?

Comment: I see the same list on both windows, except the current buffer is buried (moved to the end of the list). Have you tried with `emacs-helm.sh`?

Comment: Sorry, I should've said that the list is sorted differently for each window, the actual contents are the same.  I'll take a look at [emacs-helm.sh](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/blob/master/emacs-helm.sh) and see if it makes any difference

Comment: When I said the list is the same I also meant the order. IOW I'm not seeing the issue you're seeing.